# Graduation Project on Cryptography

Tags: cryptography

I have to do a *graduation* project:

- **Theme**: Cryptography
- **Development time**: 2 months max

I am looking for ***creative ideas*** :), not simple proof of concepts ;)

Thanks

Comment: You want creative ideas, but you want other people to come up with them? That's not very creative...

Comment: +1 for "not simple proof of concepts".Most of my projects were more or less POCs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an actual implementation of a fair [Mental Poker](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/ShamirRivestAdleman-MentalPoker.pdf) game.  There's plenty of open source card games out there that you could use for the user interface part, leaving the crypto and network protocol as the main work you'd have to do.

Comment: hmm... this is actually nice, i will consider it :) and wait for other answers...
but this is cool!!

Answer (score 2):

The original SRA implementation is neither fair (quadratic residuosity leaks) nor completely private (strategy must be revealed after showdowns).

At Certimix (http://www.certimix.com) we've developed the first real-time complete mental poker protocol, but we haven't published the paper yet.

You can implement other protocols such as:

[BS03] A. Barnett and N. Smart. Mental poker revisited. In Proc. Cryptography and Coding, volume 2898 of Lecture Notes in Computer Science, pages 370--383. Springer-Verlag, December 2003.

[CDRB03] J Castellá-Roca, J. Domingo-Ferrer, A. Riera, and J. Borrell. Practical mental poker without a ttp based on homomorphic encryption. In T. Johansson and S. Maitra, editors, Progress in Cryptology, Indocrypt'2003, number 2904 in Lecture Notes in Computer Science, pages 280--294.

[Cré86] C. Crépeau. A zero-knowledge poker protocol that achieves confidentiality of the players' strategy or how to achieve an electronic poker face. In A. M. Odlyzko, editor, Advances in Cryptology - Crypto '86, volume 263, pages 239--250, Berlin, 1986. Springer-Verlag. Lecture Notes in Computer Science.

BS03 is the best, but still is too slow for more than a couple of players.